# Suppose $G,R\subset\mathbb{R}$ are closed sets and $[c_0, d_0]\subset F\cup G$. Show that there exists $l$ such that $\lim c_n=\lim b_n=l$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Suppose $G,R\subset\mathbb{R}$ are closed sets and $[c_0, d_0]\subset F\cup G$.

If $\frac{c_0+d_0}{2}\in F$, then define $c_1=\frac{c_0+d_0}{2},d_0=d_1$; otherwise define $d_1=\frac{c_0+d_0}{2}, c_0=c_1.$

Show that there exists $b\in[c_0,d_0]$ such that $c_n, d_n\to b$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

I could recursively show that $\{c_n\}\subset F$ and $\{d_n\}\subset G$ and perhaps use Bolzano-Weierstrass. For the rest, I'm really stuck here. How do I even begin to show that their limits are equal for some $b$? What does $\{c_n\}\subset F$ and $\{d_n\}\subset G$ give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have $d_1-c_1=\frac{d_0-c_0}{2}$, and $c_1\geq c_0$, $d_1\leq d_0$. You can show by induction that $d_n-c_n=\frac{d_0-c_0}{2^n}$, and $c_{n+1}\geq c_n$, $d_{n+1}\leq d_n$.

Comment: If the two last inequalities hold, then $d_n $ is decreasing and $c_n$ is increasing, so they're both convergent and their limits exist. Then, if you take the limit of $d_n-c_n$ you see that it is equal to zero, which means the limits of $d_n$ and $c_n$ are equal. Am I missing steps/being illegal here or does this seem right?

Comment: All seems to be right..

Comment: Could you perhaps help me out with another part? -  Show that $b\in F\cap G$. I thought as both sets are closed, limits of subsequences are also in that set. However, how do I prove that $\{c_n\}\in F \forall_n$ and $\{d_n\}\in G \forall_n$?

Comment: In fact, you have perhaps an hypothesis such that $c_0\in F$ and $d_0\in G$. Then obviously $c_1\in F$ and $d_1\in G$. And the general case by induction.

Comment: I've tried to prove this inductively but I'm kind of getting stuck. The first step is clear, and then $c_{i+1}\in F $ if $c_i\in F$ OR $\frac{c_i+d_i}{2}\in F$. The second of these two I cannot seem to prove.

Comment: Let's try for $i=2$. We have $c_1\in F$ and $d_1\in G$. If $(c_1+d_1)/2$ is in $F$, then $c_2=(c_1+d_1)/2\in F$ and $d_2=d_1\in G$. If $(c_1+d_1)/2$ is not in $F$, it must be in $G$ (this is because $[c_0,d_0]\subset F\cup G$), we get $d_2\in G$ and $c_2=c_1\in F$.

Comment: How do you know $c_2=(c_1+d_1)/2\in F$? - Of course, it is only true if you already know it is an element of F.

Comment: I think this is the way your sequences are defined: We have $c_n\in F$, $d_n\in G$. If $(c_n+d_n)/2\in F$, then $c_{n+1}=(c_n+d_n)/2$, etc...

Comment: I think I have it figured out now. Thank you for your extensive help! You give me hope for my analysis course which is oh so difficult

Comment: You are welcome !